# Scraping data from Transfermarkt - how to gain full names and surnames

Tags: python, html, pandas

I have created the code below to scrape data from Transfermarkt. However, the outcome is that it does not return the full name and surname of the player but mostly (depending on the length) the surname and only the first letter of the name of the player.

```
#single team
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

headers = {'User-Agent': 
           'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36'}

page = "https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/manchester-united/startseite/verein/985"
pageTree = requests.get(page, headers=headers)
pageSoup = BeautifulSoup(pageTree.content, 'html.parser')


Players = pageSoup.find_all("span", {"class": "show-for-small"})
Values = pageSoup.find_all("td", {"class": "rechts hauptlink"})
PlayersList = []
ValuesList = []

length = len(Players)

for i in range(0,length):
    PlayersList.append(Players[i].text)
    ValuesList.append(Values[i].text)
    
df = pd.DataFrame({"Players":PlayersList,"Values":ValuesList})

df
```

And it returns the market value and the player name like "D. De Gea" instead of "David De Gea".

What's the matter? I have tried different options with HTML but they don't work.

Comment: Is it possible to give teams so we could reproduce your error?

Comment: Hi, I actually copy pasted the code and didn't spot the "teams" part. It's actually irrelevant in that part as I have used the txt later on but not in that part.

Comment: Please view a solution below. There is only one player where it keeps on showing only the first name: "Fred" ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code underneath makes it possible to display full names.
It extracts texts elements in the class "Spielprofil_tooltip" that is in the HTML of the webpage which looks like this:

```
[<a class="spielprofil_tooltip" href="/david-de-gea/profil/spieler/59377" id="59377" title="David de Gea">David de Gea</a>,
```

Only caveat is that this "spielprofil_tooltip" adds other names that are redundant (probably displayed in other tables on the websites), so for that reason I used `[0:30]` in one of the last lines.

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 
       'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36'}

page = "https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/manchester-united/startseite/verein/985"
pageTree = requests.get(page, headers=headers)
pageSoup = BeautifulSoup(pageTree.content, 'html.parser')

PlayersList = [x.text for x in pageSoup.find_all("a", {"class": "spielprofil_tooltip"})][::2] 
Values = pageSoup.find_all("td", {"class": "rechts hauptlink"})

ValuesList = []

length = len(Values)

for i in range(0,length):
    ValuesList.append(Values[i].text)

df = pd.DataFrame({"Players":PlayersList[0:30],"Values":ValuesList})

df
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks sir. Gonna try it :) By the way it works better with len(PlayerList) for me. Still you've got the flag.